# Inspecting cells in EXCEL for not allowed characters

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, user-defined-functions

I have a table a lot of cells containing text. I would like to add a function (if possible with excel standard functions) to get a text "Attention" (or similar) if the cell in reference contains a character which is not listed in a reference area.

- cell A1 contains text to be examined,
- cell B1 contains function proof_chrs (A1, list!$A$1)
- extra sheet list, contains a string "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"

Examples:

1. If A1 contains "stackoverflow" function proof_chrs returns nothing (B1 beeing empty).
2. If A1 contains "Stackoverflow" function proof_chrs returns "Attention" (B1 contains "Attention").
3. If A1 contains "stAckoverflow" function proof_chrs returns "Attention" (B1 contains "Attention").

Wishlist: Function proof_chrs should also return the position of the first "invalid" character. In the third example given it would by a 3. Returning a zero will say, there is no invalid character. New Examples:

1. If A1 contains "stackoverflow" function B1 equals to zero.
2. If A1 contains "Stackoverflow" function B1 contains 1.
3. If A1 contains "stAckoverflow" function B1 contains 3.

It would be possible to copy the function in B1 to B2, B3, ...

Comment: Note that you haven't actually asked a question or given any indication of the efforts you've made yourself so far.

Comment: I tried standard funkctions and it didn't work - I think it would be necessary to use VBA. My attempts so far: Just one character "A" in list!A1, use _=WENN(WECHSELN(A3;list!A1;"")=A3;"";"Attention")_

Comment: Extending the list by one by one to the following columns will led to _=WECHSELN(WECHSELN(WECHSELN(WECHSELN(WECHSELN(WECHSELN(WECHSELN(A4;list!G1;"");list!F1;"");list!E1;"");list!D1;"");list!C1;"");list!B1;"");list!A1;"")_, which is not really easy to manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Forbidden Characters Inspector

```vb
Option Explicit

Function proof_chrs(examineString As String, compareCharacters As String, _
  Optional CaseInSensitive1 As VbCompareMethod = 0) As Long

    Dim i As Long

    If Len(examineString) = 0 Or Len(compareCharacters) = 0 Then _
      Exit Function

    For i = 1 To Len(examineString)
        If InStr(1, compareCharacters, Mid(examineString, i, 1), _
          CaseInSensitive1) = 0 Then proof_chrs = i: Exit For
    Next i

End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Public Function proof_chrs(rng As Range, list As Range) As String
   Dim i As Long
   Dim s As String
   proof_chrs = ""
   If rng.Cells.Count = 1 And list.Count = 1 Then
       s = rng.Text
       For i = 1 To Len(s)
           If InStr(1, list.Text, Mid(s, i, 1), vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then proof_chrs = "Attention": Exit For
       Next i
   End If
End Function
```

and

```
Public Function proof_chrn(rng As Range, list As Range) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim s As String
    proof_chrn = 0
    If rng.Cells.Count = 1 And list.Count = 1 Then
        s = rng.Text
        For i = 1 To Len(s)
            If InStr(1, list.Text, Mid(s, i, 1), vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then proof_chrn = i: Exit For
        Next i
    End If
End Function
```